# How to make a Google App Engine app secure

Tags: android, ios, security, google-app-engine

I am creating a mobile app that uses Google App Engine for its server side. I am quite far along in the application so I would rather not switch to another solution, and GAE is definitely the cheapest and easiest option for me. I have had very few problems with the platform. In terms of security, I have (very well) hashed user passwords, and I use SSL for all interaction between client and server. I do, however, have some security concerns.

I am not ignorant to the fact that people are perfectly capable of reverse engineering mobile applications, iOS or Android. If someone were to discover the URLs I use to access GAE, they could easily spam my application. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent people from being able to do this. I want the only entity allowed to access GAE to be the app.

Comment: Have you tried a per-user server-generated authentication-token type of deal? So even if they somehow manage to get your Auth credentials, they won't be able to actually do anything without a key from your server

Comment: When would that key be generated? I'd have to have some mechanism to make sure that a key is only sent to an instance of the application, and not to a third party. How would I do that?

Comment: You're going to need a server-sided authentication based on the user, and then limit what the user can access to their "own data" as opposed to site-wide control. Then it wouldn't matter who got what key or from where they got it as the only data they would be able to influence is their own

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. That way even if a user created their own account outside of the application they would only be able to modify their own data! Thanks!